# ffplay / ffmpeg setup table with audio and video filters

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, media-player, waveform

Regards ,

I want to create a table with ffplay, that display the audio and video monitoring, from a signal like this:

[image: ffplay]

Unfortunately I can do only the video section:

```
ffplay  -i bar.mxf -vf "split=4[a][b][c][d],[d]vectorscope=m=color3:g=color[dd],[a]waveform=m=1:d=0:r=0:c=7[aa],\[b]waveform=m=0:d=0:r=0:c=7[bb],[c][aa]vstack[V],[bb][dd]vstack[V2],[V][V2]hstack"
```

I can't put together an audio filters with video filters, actually I can't even do the audio section, I've audio filters independent but I can't put it together.

**SHOWVOLUME**

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mka, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showvolume=f=255:b=4:w=720:h=68 [out0]"
```

**EBUR128 LOUDNESS**

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i "amovie=55.mp4,ebur128=video=1:meter=18 [out0][out1]"
```

**AVECTORSCOPE**

```
 ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mp3, asplit [a][out1]; 
    [a] avectorscope=zoom=1.3:rc=2:gc=200:bc=10:rf=1:gf=8:bf=7 [out0]"
```

> 1. How I can to set up the above table (audio and video) in a line of ffplay?
> 2. Or, How I can to set up only the audio section in a line of ffplay?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 7):

Here's the entire requirement in a single ffplay command:

```
ffplay -f lavfi  
         "amovie=in.mp4,asplit=3[sv][eb][av];
          [sv]showvolume=b=4:w=720:h=68[sv-v];
          [eb]ebur128=video=1:size=720x540:meter=18[eb-v][out1];
          [av]avectorscope=s=720x540:zoom=1.3:rc=2:gc=200:bc=10:rf=1:gf=8:bf=7[av-v];
          [sv-v][eb-v][av-v]vstack=3[1c];
          movie=in.mp4,split=4[v][wf][wfc][vs];
          [wf]waveform=m=1:d=0:r=0:c=7[wf-vus];
          [wf-vus][v]scale2ref=iw:1220-ih[wf-va][sig];
          [wf-va]setsar=1[wf-v];
          [wfc]waveform=m=0:d=0:r=0:c=7,scale=610x610,setsar=1[wfc-v];
          [vs]vectorscope=m=color3:g=color,scale=610x610,setsar=1[vs-v];
          [sig][wf-v]vstack[2c];
          [wfc-v][vs-v]vstack[3c];
          [1c][2c][3c]hstack=3,scale=1280:-1[out0]"
```

The basic principle of the stack filters is that the dimension along which they are stacked should be the same, so scale filters have been applied as needed. The scale2ref is used for the middle waveform window so that the height of the `[2c]` matches that of `[1c]`, when they are horizontally stacked. You'll have to make sure that the video's height is less than 1220. If not, scale `[v]` and feed that to scale2ref.

I suggest you supply smaller sizes in filters and scale, else you won't get close to realtime speed.

Comment: Awesome Mulvya, unfortunately as you say, there is a performance problem with ffplay