# ffplay / ffmpeg with audio and video filters

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metering

i tried to modify a already existing code for ffplay for hours, but I could not get it.
I could not find a manual for vertical and horizontal stacking parameters. I’m always getting invalid argument errors when I try to adopt it to my needs.
So I’m asking here for help.

My idea is based on that: [ffplay / ffmpeg setup table with audio and video filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105069/ffplay-ffmpeg-setup-table-with-audio-and-video-filters)

The working code that I modified a little but want to modify further without luck is:

```
ffplay -f lavfi \
         "amovie=in.mp4,asplit=3[sv][eb][av]; \
          [sv]showvolume=b=4:f=0:ds=log:c=VOLUME:w=720:h=68[sv-v]; \
          [eb]ebur128=video=1:size=720x540:meter=18[eb-v][out1]; \
          [av]avectorscope=s=720x540:zoom=1.3:rc=2:gc=200:bc=10:rf=1:gf=8:bf=7[av-v]; \
          [sv-v][eb-v][av-v]vstack=3[1c]; \
          movie=in.mp4,split=4[v][wf][wfc][vs]; \
          [wf]waveform=m=1:d=0:r=0:c=7[wf-vus]; \
          [wf-vus][v]scale2ref=iw:1220-ih[wf-va][sig]; \
          [wf-va]setsar=1[wf-v]; \
          [wfc]waveform=m=0:d=0:r=0:c=7,scale=610x610,setsar=1[wfc-v]; \
          [vs]vectorscope=m=color3:g=color,scale=610x610,setsar=1[vs-v]; \
          [sig][wf-v]vstack[2c]; \
          [wfc-v][vs-v]vstack[3c]; \
          [1c][2c][3c]hstack=3,scale=1920:-1[out0]"
```

I’d like to change it to that style - I'm not yet allowed to post images directly in this question, so I need to link it:

[Link to image how I'd like the layout to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKHaY.png)

I’d like to have the video shown in 1920x1080 (keeping aspect ratio, downscale if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi \
         "amovie=in.mp4,asplit=3[sv][eb][av]; \
          [sv]showvolume=b=4:f=0:ds=log:c=VOLUME:w=400:h=200[sv-v]; \
          [eb]ebur128=video=1:size=800x800:meter=18[eb-v][out1]; \
          [eb-v]scale=400x400[eb-v]; \
          [av]avectorscope=s=400x480:zoom=1.3:rc=2:gc=200:bc=10:rf=1:gf=8:bf=7[av-v]; \
          [sv-v][eb-v][av-v]vstack=3[1c]; \
          movie=in.mp4,scale=-1:1080[v]; \
          [1c][v]hstack=2[out0]"
```

The audio is assumed to be mono; for N channels, change showvolume `h` to N/200.

Comment: Thank you for your superfast response, @Gyan! Your code gives me an error `Video size 400x400 is too small, minimum size is 640x480`. Which I think corresponds to the ebur128 window.
When I change the ebur128 to `[eb]ebur128=video=1:size=640x480:meter=18[eb-v][out1]; \ ` I get an error `Input 1 width 640 does not match input 0 width 400`. Can you help, please?

Comment: Hi @Gyan, thanks for help, now I do get a different error: `[lavfi @ 0x7ffee3862a00] No such filter: ' '` - I studied the your code, could not find any mistake or space... Did copy/paste your code... Hmm... The "old" initial code that is too much for me still works. I'm running latest 4.0.1

Comment: Sorry, there was some trailing whitespace; removed.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gyan, that works perfectly for me now!

Comment: @gyan i only get errors saying "An input file must be specified"  i cant get this to work at all.  i know this is old  but interested in similar

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AGs93GHP   i hope this is correct

Comment: Form the entire command on a single line after removing the \

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qHDfGnDN

i also had the "  "   around the %video%  and same error